# How can I run multiple node binaries in parallel?

Tags: npm, npx

I want to build a lot of Vue.js components in parallel. At the moment I call `npx vue-cli-service build ...` several times, but each time a new instance of Node.js is started, this uses a lot of memory. Is it also possible with a single instance?

Comment: Not really since node is single threaded. You’ll also have to do some convoluted modifications to vue-culi-service

Comment: I thought there might be an implementation for npx, because there is something like that in the direction of npm.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently